# How to gain a valid input from user using loops?

Tags: python

```
from sense_emu import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()

text_red_prompt = input('How red do you want the text to be: _____ [Key Value between 0 - 255]'
text_red = int(text_red_prompt)

text_green_prompt = input('How green do you want the text to be: _____ [Key Value between 0 - 255]'
text_green = int(text_green_prompt)
```

How do I code using loops such that when a User were to input a number that is more than 255, the system will prompt the user to enter again before the system moves on to the text_green_prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try a loop like below for each of you vars

```
validInput = False
while not validInput:
    text_red_prompt = input('How red do you want the text to be: _____ [Key Value between 0 - 255]')
    text_red = int(text_red_prompt)
    if text_red >= 0 and text_red <= 255:
        validInput = True
```

Comment: Thank you Harvey, if you dont mind can you explain to me Line 2 'while not validInput'?

Comment: `while not validInput` essentially is `while validInput != True`, which means loop while the variable validInput is equal to False

this essentially creates a loop which will last forever, unless validInput is set to True

Comment: That solved my doubts and clarification. Thanks!

Comment: No Problem. If it's working you should mark the answer by clicking the tick below the vote button.